# laptop won't boot up after battery died in sleep mode

Tags: power-supply, power-jack

My laptop went to sleep mode and without charging it up for a long time, I think the battery died. When I try to charge it up with the adapter, a small light source on the side of the power port that normally indicates it's charging doesn't come on. The laptop powers itself on whenever I open the lid by default so, when I close the lid and open it, that light source blinks twice, indicating there's no power to boot it up. 
I tried removing the battery and press and hold power button for 30 seconds before inserting the battery but it still won't power on. What is the problem and how do I fix it?

P.S.
It's a HP pavilion 14 Chromebook c015dx

Comment: It could be an issue with the charger. Do you have a second charger for your laptop?

Comment: Yea I'm sure I can get access to one. I'll try that and see.

Comment: @Alex the charger was the problem. Thank you!